# Why does WordPress allow multiple page-slugs in url without triggering 404?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

The title is pretty self explanatory, but I'm trying to figure out why WordPress allows this or if it's a setting in .htaccess perhaps, but here's the example:

I have a page, lets say a "Contact" page with the slug of "contact-us".

I go to http://example.com/contact-us/ -- everything works normally

I go to http://example.com/contact-us/contact-us/contact-us/contact-us/contact-us/contact-us (I could do this a million times) and it does NOT trigger a 404 error!

Why is this? If I enter a random string of numbers, it instantly triggers 404.php, but just repeating the page-slug does not trigger a 404.

I would like the page-slug to not be able to be repeated over and over again and trigger a 404 if it even gets repeated once.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is it possibly a canonical link issue or a "nofollow". I just don't understand why WordPress is not seeing this as 404 material.

Thanks in advance for any replies, suggestions, and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve my own problem. Today I noticed that I was running two WordPress builds on the same server but one went to 404 while the other would just go back to the page. Now I knew it was a theme specific issue.

The answer is really simple actually, it was a permalink issue. In order for me to get the behavior I was looking for, I had to select "Post Name" as my permalink settings.

I previously had a custom string of options for a different style display using "Custom Structure", which I'm assuming had the "failsafe" in it.

I'm willing to switch out the extra permalink styling options in favor of the 404.

Although, those that opt to use a custom permalink structure should see if this happens to you.